# Graphics Plotfield

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, packages

A number of older books use the command:

```
<<Graphics`PlotField`
```

But *Mathematica* 10.0.2 says it cannot find it. Now, I know `VectorPlot`, but I am wondering if there is a way to install this old package `PlotField` and use it.

Comment: You should be able to perform all the functions of `PlotField` using current functions within *Mathematica*.  In short, I wouldn't try to unnecessarily invoke out-of-date code.

Comment: may be helpful : http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Graphics/PlotField.html

Comment: @george2079 Please post an anaswer ;)